# How to distribute java project built in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Till now, I have been using `Netbeans IDE` for Java Applications. To distribute applications made in Netbeans, I just click on `clean and build` and it packs the application in .jar file which resides in a `dist` directory.

Now I have made a java project in `Eclipse`. Is Eclipse has any functionality similar to `clean and build` functionality of `Netbeans` by which we can pack java applications to distribute them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can right-click the project, select Export and choose Java, then JAR as the format.

Answer (score 5):

File -> Export...

And choose Java -> JAR File. You will get a wizard to export any of your projects

Answer (score 0):

Yes it has a clean and build functionality.
clean which clean all the developed a classes from the specified location
build which builds the class files at the same specified location respectively.

To distribute a project as a jar then you have to right click on the project and select export  and in that select as jar.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a function to export the whole thing as a exetutable jar. It is under file>export.